# Swift 3 - Passing Data from one view to another

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I'll preface this question with the fact that I'm strictly a designer dabbling in xcode. I'm trying to build a 'dumb' prototype.

I am trying to set up 2 VC's. The first VC has a text field that allows a user to type in a search param and upon hitting "Return" it should pass that param to the next VC. Also on this particular VC I have a 'back' button setup in the navigation bar.

The problem I'm having is that I can't get the code for the 1st VC's back button to work with the code for passing the variable. It causes the application to crash anytime I hit the back button on the first view controller. Xcode notes that the problem is somewhere in the code for passing the variable. Here's the code for both VC's.

```
import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var searchText: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    searchText.delegate = self
    searchText.becomeFirstResponder()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var destinationController = segue.destination as! ResultsViewController
    destinationController.searchItem = searchText.text!
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if searchText.text != "" {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "resultsSegue", sender: self)
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }

   // self.view.endEditing(true)

    return true
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}



}
```

The Results View Controller's code is

```
import UIKit

class ResultsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var userSearchInputLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func btnReturnToSearch(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueBackToSearch", sender: self)
}


var searchItem = String()



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    userSearchInputLabel.text = searchItem
     self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=true;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}

@IBAction func unwindToResults(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) { }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `SearchViewController` is the `initial VC` then why would you put a `back` button there? Where you want it to `Go Back to`? I think it should not be there. 

 
Also unless you really need to do things programmatically in Xcode, you should just use `Storyboard` do embed the `SearchViewController` inside `NavigationController` (select the `Controller` then from menu: `Editor-> Embed in -> Navigation Controller`).

 
Then create `segue` from `controller icon on the top` of the `SearchViewController` to the `ResultViewController` and you could set identifier for the `segue` like you already knew (as you use it in your code). 

 
In your `ResultViewController`, if you have did the steps I mentioned above, then you don't need `button` for `returnToSearch` and you could delete the `@IBAction for btnReturnToSearch(_ sender: Any)`. As you will get the `<Back` button as `Navigation Item` on the top of `ResultViewController` to return to `SearchVeiwController` for free.

*** Update based on the last comment ****

Okay.  I finally understood your issue.  In your prepare(for:sender) . you need to . check the Segue Identifier:

> ```
> if  segue.identifier  == "CHANGE_ME_WITH_YOUR_SEGUE_FOR_RESULT_IDENTIFIER"  {
>  ...
> }
> ```

before you pass down the search result to the .  ResultViewController.  As when you segue back, you are not going to the `ResultViewController` but the `MainViewController`.

Comment: The SearchViewController isn't the initial view. There's a main VC before it which the Search VC would link back to. I just tried embedding a navigation controller into the Results View Controller. So now both the Search and Results VC's have Navigation controllers. However, the app still crashes when I'm trying to pass the value entered in the Search VC to the Results VC. When I comment out those lines of code, it works correctly (albeit not passing any information)

Comment: The console is giving me this information back "Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1066124e8) to 'Application11.ResultsViewController"

Comment: Please provide the minimum content of your project where it will still crash. Otherwise it will be difficult to help you debug the issue.

Comment: I have the Main View Controller with a tab and navigation controller embedded. From that view, it segues to the Search View Controller. It has a text field in which a user would type a search parameter and it gets passed on to the Results View Controller. In the Search View Controller, I have a left navigation bar item that I'm trying to have link back to the Main View Controller. The app is crashing when trying to segue back to the Main View Controller. The debugger seems to point to the code I'm using to pass the search variable to the Results VC.

Comment: override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let destinationController = destVC.topViewController as! 
    ResultsViewController
        destinationController.searchItem = searchText.text!
        }

Comment: Now I just found your solution. see my updated answer above. You could up vote me too if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I see what I was doing wrong. Since there were multiple segues in my Search View Controller, I needed to run a check on the segue identifier name before performing the segue that was passing data to the Results View Controller. Because I didn't have that check, it was causing the app to crash. Now I just have to figure out how to stop my tab bar navigation from disappearing...

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "resultsSegue" {
    let destVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
    let destinationController = destVC.topViewController as! ResultsViewController
    destinationController.searchItem = searchText.text!
    }
}
```